# Condition before runnning create_and_update_worksheets() function

Tags: python, if-statement

```
import socket, schedule, time

from create_and_update_xlsx_sheets import create_and_update_worksheets

REMOTE_SERVER = "www.google.com"
def is_connected():
  try:
    host = socket.gethostbyname(REMOTE_SERVER)
    s = socket.create_connection((host, 80), 2)
    return True
  except:
     pass
  return False

schedule.every().minute.do(create_and_update_worksheets())
```

I have the function `create_and_update_worksheets()` function. I want to test out the internet connection once running it. I would like to say to `schedule.every().minute.do(create_and_update_worksheets())`, ok, test the connection at most 5 times with `is_connected()`. If within that time the connection is True, then run the schedule task or otherwise pass. Any clever idea how to do that?

Be aware that I want it will wait 5 minutes between each attempt. If an attempt is True, then It will run create_and_update_worksheets() and not finish the remaining attempt. In clear, in the third attempt is successfull, then `schedule.every().minute.do(create_and_update_worksheets())` and the fourth and fifth attempts won't be tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
import socket, schedule, time

from create_and_update_xlsx_sheets import create_and_update_worksheets

REMOTE_SERVER = "www.google.com"
def is_connected():
  try:
    host = socket.gethostbyname(REMOTE_SERVER)
    s = socket.create_connection((host, 80), 2)
    return True
  except:
     pass
  time.sleep(300)
  return False

for i in range(5):
    if is_connected():
        create_and_update_worksheets()
        schedule.every().minute.do(create_and_update_worksheets())
        break
```

It checks the connection every second for 5 seconds and if it connects, it schedules the task.

Comment: Sorry in advance, my question was a bit unclear maybe, but I want it will wait 5 minutes between each attempt. If an attempt is True, then It will run `create_and_update_worksheets()` and not finish the remaining attempt as in your answer. In clear, in the third attempt is successfull, then `schedule.every().minute.do(create_and_update_worksheets())` and the fourth and fifth attempts won't be tried